# Combine two Mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement like.....

```
(1) $today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE date = '$today'";
```

Its working fine and getting the output....

And I have an input field in the same page like....

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="dt1" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="dt1" value="dt1"/>
</form>
```

And this input joined with a datepicker....

My aim is show today's data and while changing the datepicker show data on the particular date in the same page....

I given the select statement for this input is....

(2) $mydt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dt1']);
    $sql = "SELECT  FROM tables WHERE date = '$mydt'";

Independently (1) and (2) are working fine...

How will I join (1) and (2)...

That means I want to get todays data and while changing date picker i want to show that particular data of that date....

Comment: Holy ellipses, Batman...

Comment: >That means I want to get todays data and while changing date picker i want to show that particular data....

Wait, what?

Comment: That means I want to get todays data and while changing date picker i want to show that particular data of that day....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit confusing but I think what you need is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE date = '$today' OR date = '$mydt';
```

Comment: This will add other days data with todays data.....I want to get each days data saperately....

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is a little bit confusing, I don't understand what you really want.